# How to prompt device passcode as a fallback for biometrics when using react-native-keychain

Tags: react-native, biometrics, react-native-keychain

I am using react-native-keychain to manage a biometric functionality in my app. I have a custom pin set up which I want to remove and use the device passcode as a fallback to the biometrics. Either if the device does not have biometrics or permission is not given, I want to prompt the device passcode. Is it possible to do it with this library? I am unable to find a solid solution for this particular area in the documentation

I noticed these parameters given in the documentation, but after I added them I am not prompted the device passscode when biometric permissions are removed.

```
const setKeychainData = (username: string, password: string) => {
  const options: Keychain.Options = {
    service: KEYCHAIN_SERVICE,
    authenticationType: Keychain.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE.DEVICE_PASSCODE_OR_BIOMETRICS,
    accessControl: Keychain.ACCESS_CONTROL.BIOMETRY_CURRENT_SET_OR_DEVICE_PASSCODE,
  };
  return Keychain.setGenericPassword(username, password, options);
};

const getKeychainData = (message: string) => {
  const options: Keychain.Options = {
    service: KEYCHAIN_SERVICE,
    authenticationPrompt: { title: message },
    authenticationType: Keychain.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE.DEVICE_PASSCODE_OR_BIOMETRICS,
    accessControl: Keychain.ACCESS_CONTROL.BIOMETRY_ANY_OR_DEVICE_PASSCODE,
  };
  return Keychain.getGenericPassword(options);
};
```

These are the options im passing into the functions. I have used these options as shown in the documentation.

> ```
> authenticationType: Keychain.AUTHENTICATION_TYPE.DEVICE_PASSCODE_OR_BIOMETRICS,
> accessControl: Keychain.ACCESS_CONTROL.BIOMETRY_ANY_OR_DEVICE_PASSCODE,
> ```